# переопределить функцию CSSStyleSheet.prototype.rules

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,
Стандартную функцию переопределить обычно получается. Вот пример:

```js
// переопределяем
Array.prototype.pop = function () {
    console.error('pop function not working, hehe');
};
// запускаем
[1, 2, 3].pop();
```

Но у меня не получается переодпределить CSSStyleSheet:

```js
CSSStyleSheet.prototype.rules = function () {
    console.error('use .cssRules instead for compatibility');
    return false;
}
```

[image: Ошибка которую выводит консоль]

Примечание: чтоб вывело ошибку нужно запустить файл js, а не просто закинуть его в консоль.
Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ура! Таки получилось переопределить функцию....

```js
Object.defineProperty(CSSStyleSheet.prototype, 'rules', {
    get: function () {
        console.warn('use .cssRules instead of .rules for compatibility');
        return this.cssRules;
    }
});
```

Еще как вариант, можно эту чать просто удалить:

```js
delete CSSStyleSheet.prototype.rules
```

Comment: Там как-то так: https://jsfiddle.net/s23d5dxy/ (сеттер кидает ошибку).

Comment: @Other, да, да, сам всегда в хроме, но мне именно лиса показала что там геттер.. А сеттера в лисе нет.. т.е. даже ошибку не кидает